A formula for the power the disjoint union of two sets: $(A \sqcup B)^C \cong \coprod_{(D_1, D_2)} A^{D_1} \times B^{D_2}$
Let $\mathcal{C} = \mathsf{Set}$.

$\mathcal{C}$ has an initial object $\emptyset$.

Given an object $C \in \mathcal{C}$, define $\operatorname{SubObjPairs}(C)$ to be the category of complementary pairs of subobjects of $C$. In this category, the objects are pairs $(D_1, D_2)$ together with monomorphisms $\iota_1: D_1 \hookrightarrow C$ and $\iota_2: D_2 \hookrightarrow C$ such that in the category of subobjects of $C$, the product of $D_1$ and $D_2$ is $\emptyset$ and the coproduct of $D_1$ and $D_2$ is $C$. The morphisms are obvious commutative diagrams.

Let $\operatorname{SubObjPairs}'(C)$ be the set of objects of $\operatorname{SubObjPairs}(C)$ up to isomorphism.

A morphism $f: C_1 \to C_2$ induces a functor $\operatorname{SubObjPairs}(C_2) \to \operatorname{SubObjPairs}(C_1)$ by taking pullbacks along $f$.

This functor induces a set map $\operatorname{SubObjPairs}'(C_2) \to \operatorname{SubObjPairs}'(C_1)$.

Given $A, B, C \in \mathcal{C}$, we can consider
$$
\coprod_{(D_1, D_2) \in \operatorname{SubObjPairs}'(C)} A^{D_1} \times B^{D_2}
$$
This is obviously functorial in $A$ and $B$ and also contravariantly functorial in $C$.

The question: How can we show that the following are naturally isomorphic in $A$, $B$ and $C$?
$$
(A \sqcup B)^C \cong \coprod_{(D_1, D_2) \in \operatorname{SubObjPairs}'(C)} A^{D_1} \times B^{D_2}
$$

Does this work for any categories other than $\mathcal{C} = \mathsf{Set}$?



The proof of the equivalence is elementary set theory. For a map of sets $f : C \to A_1 + A_2$ consider the complementary subsets $C_1 := f^{-1}(A_1)$, $C_2 := f^{-1}(A_2)$, then you get maps $f_1 : C_1 \to A_1$, $f_2 : C_2 \to A_2$ by restricting $f$.
Conversely, for maps $f_1 : C_1 \to A_1$, $f_2 : C_2 \to A_2$ on complementary subsets we define $f : C \to A_1+A_2$ by extending these maps.
This property of coproducts is abstracted into the notion of an extensive category.

Thanks! Could you elaborate a bit more on extensive categories? I don't find the definition on the nLab very transparent. Perhaps you could illuminate the definition by showing how it applies in this case.

I will not do that. The request "I don't understand [any concept]" is not focused enough. Please follow the links mentioned at the nlab.

Pulling back $f : C \to A \sqcup B$ along the coproduct inclusions gives you maps $D_1 \to A$ and $D_2 \to B$, and stability of coproducts under pullback (which is half of the condition of extensivity) ensures that $C \cong D_1 \sqcup D_2$.
